# How to get the process name based on hwnd in C

Tags: c, winapi

**Programming language:** C

**Objective:** Get the process id and name based on the current hwnd.

**Current code:**

```
HWND hwnd;
DWORD process_ID;
PWSTR process_name = NULL;

hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
process_ID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&process_ID)
process_name = ????
```

I am not sure if I am passing correctly the arguments to the function GetWindowThreadProcessId. I found on Internet that I could use GetModuleFileNameW to get the process name but I cannot understand the documentation. Please forgive me if it is too easy to solve. I am starting in the world of C. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23069703/how-to-get-the-process-name-from-the-PID-winapi-C-visual-C-6-0.html) help?

Comment: Next step is `OpenProcess()` to get a process HANDLE from the process ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) is a *thread* ID, not a *process* ID, so DO NOT assign that return value to your `process_ID` variable, or else it will overwrite the value that was output by the `lpdwProcessId` parameter.

```cpp
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();

DWORD process_ID = 0;
if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &process_ID))
{
    // get the process name ...
}
else
{
    // error handling ...
}
```

Once you have the process ID, you can pass it to [`OpenProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) to get a `HANDLE` to the running process, and then use that `HANDLE` with either [`GetModuleFileNameEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexw), [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamew) (XP+), or [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew) (Vista+) to get the full path and filename of that process's EXE file:

```cpp
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, process_ID);
if (hProcess)
{
    WCHAR process_name[MAX_PATH] = {};
    if (GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, process_name, MAX_PATH))
    {
        // use process_name as needed...
    }
    else
    {
        // error handling ...
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
else
{
    // error handling ...
}
```

```cpp
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, process_ID);
if (hProcess)
{
    WCHAR process_name[MAX_PATH] = {};
    if (GetProcessImageFileNameW(hProcess, process_name, MAX_PATH))
    {
        // use process_name as needed...
    }
    else
    {
        // error handling ...
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
else
{
    // error handling ...
}
```

```cpp
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, process_ID);
if (hProcess)
{
    WCHAR process_name[MAX_PATH] = {};
    DWORD size = MAX_PATH;
    if (QueryFullProcessImageNameW(hProcess, 0, process_name, &size))
    {
        // use process_name as needed...
    }
    else
    {
        // error handling ...
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
else
{
    // error handling ...
}
```

Comment: sorry for the delay in answering. Thank you so much for your help, It worked perfectly. I have a further question regarding error handling. If I want to do process_name="Process failed", but process_name is WCHAR and I do not know how I could assign it. Anyway, you helped me a lot, I appreciate your time with my question, I learned a lot.

Comment: @sergioMoreno use `lstrcpyW()` or equivalent function, eg: `lstrcpyW(process_name, L”Process failed”);`